# How to wait for an element which does not come always in a page using webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Could anybody throw me some idea on my query?

Query:
In my application, there is a pop up which comes frequently, but some times it does not come.
I have to check whether the pop up is there or not, and then perform action on that. This pop up also takes some time to be appeared in the page.

My Solution:
First I waited for the pop up by explicit wait condition.
Then by a if loop i m checking whether the pop up is displayed on the page or not. 
if displayed then do actions, else do other action.

Now, if the pop up does not come, i m getting time out exception.

Here is my code:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait_1 = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
 .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
 .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
 .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
 .ignoring(TimeoutException.class);

 //getting time out exception if pop up does not exists
 wait_1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("some id")));

 if(driver.findElement(By.id("some id")).isDisplayed()) { 
 System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("some id")).getText());
 //click some elements
 }
 else{
 // `enter code here`
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
int count = 0;
do {
    if (driver.getWindowHandles().size() > 1) {
        String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> iterator = windowHandles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String handle = iterator.next();
            if (!handle.contains(parentWindow)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(handle);
                // Alert is present do something
            }
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
        break;
    }
    count++;
} while (count < 100);
```

This will wait untill alert apprears or count reached to 100. You can change the count value as per your requirements.